# onchange event should trigger at the time of onclick event in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dropdown, onchange

in that component I need to print **onenumber** as a text in the textbox in a way like I am selecting one from dropdown and typing number , so at a time we are able to type text in a text box and selecting text from the dropdown ,and in on change function triggered all time like if you type text and select the dropdown as well ,so what should I changed in the on Change event?

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  function handleClick(event) {
    setVal(event.target.innerHTML);
    setShow(false);
  }
  function handleChange(event) {
    setVal(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={val}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyUp={handleClick}
      />
      {show && (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "180px",
            height: "80px",
            background: "pink"
          }}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          <div>one</div>
          <div>two</div>
          <div>three</div>
          <div>four</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react";

function Test() {


const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
const [val, setVal] = useState("");

function handleClick(event, what) {
    if (what === 'click') { setVal(event.target.innerHTML) }
    setShow(false);
}

function handleChange(event) {
    setVal(event.target.value);
}
return (
    <div className="App">
        <input
            type="text"
            value={val}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onKeyUp={(e) => handleClick(e, 'keyup')}
        />
        {show && (
            <div
                style={{
                    width: "180px",
                    height: "80px",
                    background: "pink"
                }}
                onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, 'click')}
            >
                <div>one</div>
                <div>two</div>
                <div>three</div>
                <div>four</div>
            </div>
        )}
    </div>
);
}



export default Test
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the condition, That show state is true of false in handleChange and then print number as a text in the textbox

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).